# Dim Form as as specific Form with if-statement

Tags: vb.net, forms, if-statement

I have a `Sub`, which works for two different `Forms`. When I call the `Sub` from one of those forms I give the `Form` to the `Sub` as a parameter.

How can I set the correct for as a variable in the `Sub`?

Here are two ways I have tried this, but they do not work.

```vb
Shared Sub SetDataGridViewg(ByRef Form As Form, AusAuftrag As Boolean)
    ' ERROR: A common type can not be derived, and Option Strict On does not allow the assumption of the Object type.
    Dim AdressenÜbersicht = If(AusAuftrag, CType(Form, AdressenÜbersichtAusAuftrag), CType(Form, Startseite))

    ' ERROR: The variable "AdressenÜbersicht" hides a variable in an enclosing block.
    If AusAuftrag Then
        Dim AdressenÜbersicht As AdressenÜbersichtAusAuftrag = CType(Form, AdressenÜbersichtAusAuftrag)
    Else
        Dim AdressenÜbersicht As Startseite = CType(Form, Startseite)
    End If

    ' ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Option Strict is On so I get the error, The goal is that the variable AdressenÜberischt is AdressenÜbersichtAusAuftrag or Startseite (both Forms), depands if AusAuftrag is true or false. So that I can access the Controls in one of this form with the variable

Comment: What error specifically are you getting on which line? Also, i wouldn't use class names as variable names (`ByRef Form As Form`), it works fine in many cases but imo it's just bad form (excuse the pun). It may or may not be related to your error.

Comment: I have added the Error for boths trys. Thanks for the hint, I will change this

Comment: Since there's a condition, the type of `AdressenÜbersicht` can only be determined at runtime, so you instead have an object. You could use generics (not well suited here), or oveload `SetDataGridViewg`, or use something like this: `If AusAuftrag Then Dim form = DirectCast(myForm, AdressenÜbersichtAusAuftrag) form.[Control].[Property] = Something
Else Dim form = DirectCast(myForm, Startseite) form.[Control].[Property] = Somethingelse End If`.

Comment: Thanks, First I try to Dim inside the If but then I can not use the variable later in the Sub, outside of the dim

Comment: And right, now I have used overloads and is works thanks

Comment: How are you intending to use `AdressenÜbersicht`? I think the cleaner way here would be to have both `AdressenÜbersichtAusAuftrag` and `Startseite` implement a common interface and consistently use that type.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Both Forms has some same fileds so I will make the changes in this Sub in the form which called the sub. DO you have an example for this?

Comment: E.g. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/interfaces/). Interfaces do not work with fields. So, encapsulate the fields in properties, add the properties to an interface (which then tells you that a certain class has these properties), and implement the interface in your classes.